# What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I stumbled onto this question: [how to set up glassfish-resource.xml and web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426128/how-to-set-up-glassfish-resource-xml-and-web-xml) which helped me to solve my issue.  However, I almost completely bypassed it because there were no answers to it.  Fortunately, I kept tabbing back and forth between my issue and re-reading his question and got to the last section of his question in which he posts his ultimate solution.

I'm going to leave a comment saying that it would be good to simply answer his own question.  However, considering the age of the question and the last time the user has been seen, I think the likelihood of him returning is low.  Should I answer his question with how I solved his solution while also adding maybe some descriptions as to why this is a factor or maybe what the issue was or is there any way to edit the question so as to give the questioner credit?

Comment: This [Meta SE question of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114314/should-we-really-be-suggesting-that-people-put-the-answer-in-the-question) may be the reason why the answer was added in the first place.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Along the lines of what [deceze says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267437/456814), what I do in these situations is to edit the answer out of the question, and place it into a community wiki answer, so that I don't earn any rep from upvotes. I attribute the answer to the original poster.

It's probably best to just leave a comment to the OP explaining that answers should not go into questions though, and that they can edit out the answer and answer their own question. If they don't respond in a couple of days, then I would go ahead and just do the edit.

After doing the edit and community wiki answer, I also leave a comment on the question to the original poster that if they'd like to answer their question so that they earn rep, they can just leave a comment on the community wiki answer, and I'll delete it.

Comment: I would not agree on that and rather answer without the Community option. If you take the time and nerves to create an answer that meets the community standards (and not just one word or just a copy of the comment which likely is not enough for a full answer), then it is perfectly fine to answer. Reputation on this answer is the reward for the decision and working time that you invested to improve the Q/A universe. Interestingly, this user has stopped working on SE, perhaps the call for altruism was rather influenced by too little thriving for reputation?

Answer (score 15):

That is exactly the reason to post answers as answers, to make it obvious to anyone what the problem and what the solution is, and that a solution *exists*. If it doesn't seem likely that the user returns, go ahead and post the solution and possibly edit the question to remove the solution from it.

Comment: Should I make mention to OP solving the problem or should it just look like a regular question leading to an answer?  I only ask because the OP **did** solve the problem, I don't want to look like a thief.

Comment: If you're just going to copy and paste what the OP wrote from the Q into an A, then certainly give as much attribution as necessary. But if you're mostly going to add your own solution based on hints provided by the OP, give a nod in the OP's direction but don't bend over backwards.

Answer (score 9):

> Should I answer his question with how I solved his solution while also adding maybe some descriptions as to why this is a factor or maybe what the issue was?

Yes. that would be the way to go. Considering the vast number of questions on Stack Overflow that go unanswered for ages, I fully support answering questions which are old (even if they are answered, provided you have something more to add). This will help someone facing the same issue.

PS: It is also *good* to update old answers if necessary. 
As far as the credits are concerned, I suggest mentioning *as the OP has mentioned...* , that way, you won't be accused of *plagiarism*.