# Answer question on behalf of OP

Tags: feature-request, self-answer

Many new OPs answer their own questions by editing them, such as this one here:

[Error creating JClouds SwiftApi: Provider org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.KeystoneApiMetadata could not be instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25121530/solved-error-creating-jclouds-swiftapi)

Instead of asking them to answer their own questions through Stack Overflow answers, I could just as well roll back the question again and move the answer into an actual answer. But I'd like to do so in the name of the OP.

Would that be a useful feature? Would it pull its weight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)

Comment: @Akshay: this is a feature request to do something different.

Answer (score 5):

The correct thing to do in such cases is to post the answer yourself, making it a Community Wiki post:

> [image: cw checkbox]

Do so a day or two after you poked the question asker to post the answer themselves; if the question is still quite new, the OP cannot post an answer themselves yet as they have to wait 8 hours after posting.

If you cannot wait, be prepared to take down the CW answer again if the OP *really* wants to post an answer themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the community wiki feature (after all this time!) *"Do so a day or two after you poked"* - Nope, I don't take SO moderation *that* seriously, sorry :-) *"if the question is still quite new, the OP cannot post an answer themselves yet as they have to wait 8 hours after posting."* - Then, that is the problem here, I guess... Not sure if those 8 hours are really good (in this particular case)

Comment: I wouldn't even wait; I've already made the changes.

Comment: @LukasEder: I tend to star the post and see what they are up to a few days later.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: check; I agree that not waiting is a fine option too, provided you are prepared to take it down again if the OP wants to create their own.

Comment: Yet, I still think that creating an answer on behalf of someone could be a good moderation tool (obviously only available to high rep) - much better than creating a community wiki. The fact that @RobertHarvey is now the author of the answer looks quite weird and is probably confusing the OP

Comment: @LukasEder: I disagree; it would be way too easy to abuse that and post 'other' things the OP would not be happy with having their name attached to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, give this feature to 50k rep people or so. Right now, it makes absolutely no sense. The answer now says *"Thanks to Ignasi Barrera, **I** was able to sort this [...]"* in the name of Robert Harvey

Comment: @LukasEder: but it is *rarely needed*, even more so for other, smaller sites. If you find the CW confusing, then edit that post a little; *The OP solved this with* or similar. It is a CW post so editing is easy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Now you're saying that a third user should edit an answer that was given by a second user on behalf of a first user. Yet, you're afraid of people abusing that and posting "other" things... :) When in fact, the first user should've given an answer, but they cannot because of the 8 hours. Clearly, there's a process smell here, no? I asked the question because I encountered about 5 such issues today...

Comment: @LukasEder: so how is the user going to learn to do it the right way then? I really don't want to encourage a 'someone will clean this up for me' attitude either.

Comment: If this is a feature, then the user will get an automated notification explaining what had happened... The user went through the lengths of *trying* to do it right, just with the wrong tool. I think you may be a bit overly negative towards users in general... :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters As I commented on [the related MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114314/should-we-really-be-suggesting-that-people-put-the-answer-in-the-question), several of the limitations placed on new users already train them to do the wrong thing, as collateral damage from stopping them doing a different wrong thing. For comments-as-answers, I believe there is already a mod tool to demonstrate the right way to do it.

Comment: @IMSoP: There already is? But only for moderators, then?

Comment: @LukasEder Not for this case, but I *think* when an answer is flagged "not an answer, should be a comment", the moderator is able to convert it into one rather than deleting it. I'm not 100% sure, though, as I've never seen what the diamond tools look like.

Comment: @IMSoP: Ah yes, I've seen that happen numerous times before. I guess that comments in answers are a more common situation than answers in questions...

Answer (score 4):

Roll back the edit and leave a comment asking the OP to repost the solution as an answer.

The problem is that unless you self answer when you post you can't answer until 8 hours have passed after posting the question.

See this Meta Stack Exchange question for more on this:

> [Should we really be suggesting that people put the answer in the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114314/should-we-really-be-suggesting-that-people-put-the-answer-in-the-question)

If they don't post the answer then feel free to post the answer yourself - though you may want to CW the answer to avoid accusations of just being after the rep.

Comment: +1 for the link to the previous discussion on MSE, which gets to the heart of the "process smell", as Lukas Elder put it.