# Should you put an answer to your own question and mark it as the accepted answer or update your question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

This mainly relates to when you've asked a question, no ones given you a suitable answer and then you come up with it yourself.

So my question is, if you have this situation should you post the answer as an answer and then accept it (in 3 days I think)? To me this has the benefit of immediately showing the question as answered. So for those looking to help answering questions they don't waste their time clicking on your question. In addition, those looking for answers can see that it's been answered and is therefore more likely to help them if they're facing the same problem.

Alternatively, should you update your question stating what your fix / solution was? I've seen this done and suggested by other users. However, I can't see how this would be better than openly showing your question has been answered. I can't really see the benefit of this over the first 1.

So what's the best practice?

Comment: See also: [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/3524344)

Comment: @Gas - I read that 1 before writing this and whilst the answer may imply something similar to what lostsock has posted its not the same question. They're asking if you can answer your own questions. I know you can, but wanted to know whether this was the best practice compared to simply updating your own question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

SE is a Question and Answer site.

We have a spot for questions, and a spot for answers.

So always leave an answer in the answer spot.

**Yes, leave your own answer and accept it.**

We even have a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for answering your own question with a score of 3 or more. This is to encourage users to post answers to their own questions, that aren't already answered correctly.

When you see posts where the questioner has edited their question to put in the answer there, it's best practice to move the answer as an answer. Just copy paste the answer, click the *community wiki* checkbox and post the answer. And then edit out the answer from the question.

Comment: I definitely agree with this for the reasons posted initially.

Comment: *When you see posts ...* - Shouldn't the questioner be given the chance/encouragement to do this themselves, perhaps with an encouraging comment?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon it depends. You could look at their profile to see when their last access date is. If they appear to be active on the site still, you can leave a comment for them to do so..just make sure to check back in 2 days to do it yourself if they still haven't.