# Is it on topic to post a question, with what you think is the answer and have it validated

Tags: discussion

I have a question, and I **think** I know the answer but having some one confirm if my answer is right or not is my question.

Asking this type of question has issues, becuase if I'm right, the answer would have to be "yes".

So let's use a real example:

> When I do something in this language, the following result occurs:
>
> Result details
>
> I think the reason for this is because of the reason. Can any one confirm this is right?

Is it OK to ask questions which may result in very short, even one word style answers (regardless of the min words limits etc)! Or does that make it off topic?

(My only alternative I can think of is to post what I think is the asnwer and see if it's upvoted or downvoted)

Comment: Meh, there are not a lot of users that think "You are right" is a suitable answer.  If you don't get an answer then you were right.  Perhaps :)  Just show your research leading up to your answer.

Comment: First answer, accepted: "Yes.". Second answer, more upvotes than accepted answer: "No."

Answer (score 13):

I would reword it:

> When I do something in this language, the following result occurs:
>
> Result details X
>
> Why does X happen?<sup>[1]</sup> Is it because of reason Y?<sup>[2]</sup>

This changes two things: it actually makes your question a question that can be answered([1]) and shows your train of thought ([2]), which could be interpreted as that you actually did some research.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is fine, and shows that you've been thinking about your problem - rather than just crashing in and asking for help.

The answer is likely to be longer than just "Yes" or "No". The answer is quite likely to be "Yes, because... " or "No, because...". You don't just want to know *that* something is right or wrong; you want to understand *why*. A good answer, even when just validating your thinking, will give you that "why".

Answer (score 1):

What you propose may not be closed, and may not get downvotes but I'm not a fan of it because **it is really not an optimal way of writing for SO.**

My advice for self-answered questions is to play dumb, but not too dumb.  Pretend that you don't already have an explanation for it. What methods would you use to figure it out? What tests would you perform? What documentation would you read? Write your question in a way that presents the problem and the tests you performed and the results you got and detail what it is you already know from reading the documentation. (This is where a lot of self-answered questions fail: the user already knows the answer so the question is a perfunctory one-liner rather than an actual problem.)

**Then, post an answer that explains why you think the thing that puzzles you happens. The community will comment and vote on your answer.** So you'll soon know whether or not you were right.

The way you suggest doing it, then in the case where your research is 100% right on the money and you explained the reason why perfectly, then what are people supposed to answer?? "Yes, you're right." When it comes to reputation, votes and acceptance, I'd rather see them attached to your excellent explanation rather than "Yes, you're right."

---

I am not swayed but the argument that if the OP is unsure, then they should not post their explanation as an actual answer. If what the OP has in hand is a wild guess, then they should not post their wild guess *at all*, be it in the question or the answer. If they have done their homework, which is what they should do *in any case* when they post on SO, they have more than a wild guess in hand. They may still have an honest mistake but honest mistakes are posted all the time on SO. If the OP happens to make an honest mistake, their honest mistake does not necessitate special consideration. It is not worse than any other honest mistake posted on SO.

Moreover, what I'm suggesting here is consistent with a long-established custom of SO: **when users post answers in their question, we ask them to post their answer as answers**. (See [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).) Whenever I run into a question that contains an answer, I edit the question to remove the answer, and leave a comment informing the OP that as a matter of editorial practice, answers belong in actual answers, not in questions, and inviting them to post an actual answer. In some case, I've posted the answer myself as CW, if circumstances called for it. **I've never ever encountered the notion that there is an exception to the no-answers-in-questions-principle if the OP states that they are unsure about their answer.** And I do not think that such exception should exist.

What the OP is presenting here is not materially different from any other run-of-the-mill situation where an answer is presented in a question.

Comment: _"post an answer that explains why you think the thing that puzzles you happens"_ - if you're really not certain of that, don't post it as an answer. Because then you're posting an answer in order to get feedback on that answer, which is not how the system works.

Comment: If it is a wild guess, then it is inappropriate, whether in an answer or in a question. We always get feedback on answers. That's how the system works. All the upvotes I got, and the few downvotes are feedback.

Comment: If, and that's how I interpret OP's question, one wants to know whether their assumptions are correct and wants to do so by using Stack Overflow, then post both the assumptions and an answerable question _in that question_. In that scenario you don't post the question as a question and your assumption as an answer. Also, votes on answers hardly ever indicate quality or correctness of that answer.

Comment: I'm giving more credit to the OP than you are, I think.

Comment: I'm basing my claims on OP's desire to _"having some one confirm if my answer is right or not"_. In that case you don't post a self-answer to a naive question in order to let others vote on the "correctness" of the answer. Instead seek to phrase the question in such a way that your assumptions are either validated or disproved by the answer to the actual question.

Comment: You're assuming a "naive question". I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: I have done this before actually and there are times when that is required (to play dumb), but playing dumb helps to define the type of answer you want (such as either an answer, or even an unexpected answer which then provides new considerations for new solutions). In this case though, I'm more interested in being corrected than having a solution.I also don't think the purpose of the site is about voting, surely it's about it being a Q and A? But, I do fully take on your points, and I fully understand  where you're coming from. I knew my question would solicite debate, but felt it best to ask

Comment: Using this strategy is effectively using [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law)... which may more may not be beneficial for the site as a whole. Personally I don't see a huge problem with it if you genuinely think your answer is probably right... But it's probably more in the spirit of the site to post both your question and uncertain solution in the question body.