# Why was my work towards an answer removed from my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers

Working from some of the helpful comments on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588059/are-these-integers-misaligned-and-should-i-even-care), I updated my question with my progress towards a solution that very closely mirrored an answer to come a few seconds later.

I admit to feeling proud to arrive to the same conclusions.  But that edit was removed by another user because "it contained the answer".

Is this normal, or would I be justified in reverting this edit?

I wouldn't care, but employers look at this place and I had a half-joke I liked in that edit...

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers, not as edits to the question. This is to avoid confusion.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to add you may add a comment to the answer you used/adapted, or you may simply post your own answer, linking to the answer from which you have taken and clarify how you adapted it & why. Looking at your edit: you just replaced `x` with `temp`, so posting a new answer seems useless.

Comment: Some of the highest voted 'answers' on my profile are those where I simply took the answer from the question put that information into an actual separate answer. It's make things so much clearer on this site and is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The edit was good. Remember we have an API here, which supplies question posts and answer posts as separate entities. From an engineering perspective, allowing people to post answers in questions is just as bad as allowing people to post questions in answers - it reduces the utility of the API and would be regarded as data that required extra cleaning.

Comment: Also note that jokes and half-jokes are noise, so even if your progress toward an answer was kept, the half-joke would and should be removed anyway. I also don't see what it has to do with employers possibly reading a question you've posted.

Comment: @ouflak Ethically such answers should be marked Community Wiki.

Comment: @TylerH, That's interesting. I never really considered the 'ethics' of moving an answer out of the question and into its own proper answer. I just figured it was good house cleaning for what is fundamentally supposed to be a Q/A site.

Comment: @ouflak It's definitely good housecleaning and appreciated. The ethics part comes into play with the fact that a user is simply doing a bit of housecleaning by moving someone else's work from a question to an answer. Even though they may provide proper citation, it's still just moving someone else's work down on the screen by 400px; upvotes gained on a non-CW post then provide the poster with reputation and privileges that they did not actually earn, so to speak. Setting such posts as CW lets people vote on it without any concern for someone gaining reputation for this act.

Comment: @ouflak After my initial comment, I checked with the mods on this because I did not want to espouse a strong view on the matter if it was wrong or not enforced, and they said there is no hard and fast rule about it. However, [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) on the subject was found, and it does seem to agree with what I suggested.

Comment: The one thing I do appreciate is you coming here and asking if it is ok, rather than just reverting it as many do. Thank you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The types of edits that are useful in a questions are:

- To clarify the question
- To format the question
- Correct grammar and spelling

The types of edits that don't belong in a question are:

- Edits that show how the questioner arrived at a solution
- Changes that change the original question (once it has an answer)
- Writing things like "Solved"
- Writing the word "Edit/ed" when making an edit, as it's irrelevant and can be seen in the revision history

This question discusses one possible consequence of the answer being edited into the question. [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que). If no one posts an answer, people browsing for solutions may skip the post thinking it has no answers.

Also see:

> [When should I edit posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

Comment: It might help to explain the reasons behind this.

Comment: Personally I find the "EDIT" section helpful to clearly separate new information that wasn't there when I or others wrote answers or comments. Without it, those comments/answers can seem confusing or misleading.

Comment: @SteveBennett "Note: I edited this to add X and Y, after some answers where made." does that better than **EDIT:** because **EDIT:** encourages you to generate a question that is fragmented and historical; we want the primary document to be readable as-is in the present.  Having notes saying what changed is sometimes useful, but shouldn't be the primary structure of the document.  The exact historical details are available to anyone who really needs them, but the primary use of a Q&A is someone googling the question a year later and looking for an answer.

Comment: @Dukeling They seem pretty self-explanatory to me. Though I suppose it's better to be thorough than ambiguous.

Comment: @Dukeling I could, but I thought it was a simple explanation. I can add some links, would that help?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Since users do all of the things mentioned here as not belonging in a question, it's probably not that self-explanatory.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Links could work. I imagine we have Meta posts dedicated to discussing each of the points you mentioned (or at least the last 3).

Comment: @Dukeling I suppose everything's relative. Though I submit that people do things they obviously shouldn't all the time, and telling them _why_ they shouldn't is not likely to change things :P There's also a "ah, now you've pointed it out it's obvious" factor, potentially. You may not have originally realised that the supermarket closes at 4pm on a Sunday, but once you find out you probably don't need to bother asking why that's the case.

Comment: @Dukeling what do you think of the edit?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Ok, I guess I understand your position, it just doesn't particularly resonate with me. I'm often more motivated by solving the specific problems of specific people than vague "build a Q&A database" goals. And it's my time I'm volunteering, so I'm only willing to be dictated to to a certain extent.

Comment: @SteveBennett in which case, [so] isn't a good fit for you. You're welcome to spend your time elsewhere.

Comment: No, because that's not how volunteer organisations work. You don't tell someone to leave because of one small area of disagreement. And especially not when they've been here longer, and have 4 times the rep :)

Comment: @Lankymart I have to agree with Steve Bennett on that, not a helpful comment. Why did you post that?

Comment: @YvetteColomb their comment imo isn’t helpful either. There are too many who take the “I'm volunteering my time so I do what I like” approach. It’s been stated time and time again what [so] is, to butt against that because they feel privileged struck a nerve.

Comment: @Lankymart thanks for explaining that. Yeh I understand that. The site can be intense at times, so  it's pretty easy to react with a knee jerk response. I think Steve was ok in this instance. He's just stating what he prefers in terms of questions and that's ok too, as does Yakk-Adam.

Answer (score 8):

> I updated my question with my progress towards a solution

I believe it's totally fine to edit progress into question. Make sure the question is still the **same** and don't use [anti-patterns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/299295) (though I disagree with it, that's another disccusion).

The point is this: all of those findings should be **failed** attempts. So that you still have the question to be answered.

As soon as you find something which works for you, it's the **answer**. Just [post it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It doesn't prevent others from posting a *better* answer if there is any.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't Jeopardy.  Answers should be posted in the Answer box, not in the question box.

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's what Sinatr's answer says.

Comment: Good point, include failed attempts, not the final solution

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to include a partial solution when you initially post your question, or in response to "what have you tried?" comments. However, you certainly shouldn't make any substantial edits to your questions once relevant answers start rolling in. Sometimes it makes sense to add info to the question when you realise that answerers are misinterpreting what the code needs to do, or what the data looks like, but ideally that should happen before any answers are submitted. The key point here is that you shouldn't make major changes to your question that invalidate those existing answers. If you *do* need to make major changes then the best thing to do is to realise that you accidentally asked the wrong question, and to start again with a fresh question, possibly linking it to the old one.

You definitely should *not* add material to your question that was written in the answers. Eg, "Joe said to use `this code`, but when I tried it on my actual data, I got `this wrong result`". That doesn't work well with the Stack Exchange Q & A format. In that format one person submits a question, and (hopefully :)) people submit answers in response to it. It's not designed for an interactive back-and-forth tutorial session. If you need that sort of thing it may be possible to do that to some extent in a chat room.

However, if you want to grab information from one or more of the submitted answers and combine that into your own solution you are certainly welcome to do that, but you need to post it in the Answers section, not add it to the question. (And of course your answer should mention the names of the people whose code you've copied). If you write some code that way which is only a partial solution that doesn't do what you really want, then you *shouldn't* post it as an answer. Instead, post it in a follow-up question, linking back to the original question.