# Failed "first question" review with an answer as the question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32030012) (at the time [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72415814/4) was current).

The "question" is basically a blog post. It vaguely describes a question and then posts a solution as part of the question. I voted to close as unclear, then submitted the review as "Other action", which led to a failed review audit.

This question should *not* be used as an audit since it is not a question.

Comment: Isn't it the policy, when someone takes a question and edits an answer into it, to rollback the edit and possibly repost the answer (with attribution)? If you clicked edit then you wouldn't have failed this type of audit, iirc.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit adding the solution to the question, as well as suggested that they should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Laurel, what "policy" are you referring to? I'm tired of arbitrary rules about what constitutes a "good" review, especially when the "rules" are scattered across a dozen or more questions and review audit questions aren't reviewed by humans. It's infuriating. The system is designed to "trap" reviewers rather than to get reviews done competently. Do they really want to stop active reviewers from participating? Alienating active reviewers isn't a great idea when they're trying to launch things like the Staging Ground.

Comment: Also, the "someone" who edited an answer into the question in this case is OP. I interpret that as part of the question, not some random person not understanding how SO works.

Comment: See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434/6083675). Yes, it's almost always the OP who adds their answer to the question. (Everyone else will either have 2k rep and probably know better or have their suggested edit rejected.)

Comment: @Laurel, thank you, but the review audit system is fundamentally broken. I'm very, very close to just not participating anymore. Users who believe in SO and invest in it almost invariably get chewed up by things like this. It's very disappointing. SE is throwing a ton of value out with the bathwater.

Comment: Users shouldn't have to find and read a dozen or more meta posts to participate properly.

Comment: And let's not lose sight of the fact of what [the question asked before the edit with the "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72415814/2). It wasn't great. It might _barely_ be on-topic, but it's pretty close to the line. Could have been closed as "needs detail" or "needs debugging information" IMO. I don't think any revision of this question should be used as an audit.

Comment: IIRC, the only way to prevent a question from being used as an audit is for the community opinion of it to *not* be unanimous. Right now it’s still sitting at +12/-0. No one has said it’s not a good question yet.

Comment: This is an example of why I very quickly stopped reviewing.

Comment: I just read this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) about review audits, and although I understand it is infuriating to fail a review audit, the explanation of review audits in the answer makes it sound like it's not so bad. (maybe it's out of date)

Comment: @Chris *"Users shouldn't have to find and read a dozen or more meta posts to participate properly. "* - I 100% agree, it *sucks*. The meta part, not the reading part. It is perfectly normal that people need to inform themselves before they can participate properly, there is no real way we can do on the job training here. Alas like so many things about this site, it's far from perfect. Hence why meta is used to fill some gaps.

Comment: It's also infuriating when one fails an audit and posts about it here and the response is invariably something along the lines of "it should have been obvious it was an audit question" followed by "if you've any doubt it's an audit open the question in a fresh tab". When I was active in the review queues it felt like every 5th review was an audit. I don't want to spend 20% of my time & effort proving I can identify audit questions.

Comment: @Chris You ask, "Do they really want to stop active reviewers from participating?" I'm brand new at this and that's exactly what happened today with me. I don't intend to participate in any more reviews.

Comment: Detect and skip all audits. No, I will not tell you how.

Answer (score 9):

> Congratulations! You are the `<insert arbitrary large integer>`<sup>th</sup> reviewer to have fallen foul of the seriously
> Flawed Automated Review Queue Audit System (FARQAS).

Now, although I strongly sympathize with your frustration and anger over this event, let's *try* to add some context …

1. Unless you should fail *multiple* audits (typically, at least 3) in a short spell of time (30 days), then your review queue privileges will *not* be subject to suspension. To encounter one such terrible audit (and that *was* terrible) is an all-too-frequent event; however, stumbling across three in a month would be *extremely* unlucky and is (hopefully) very rare. <sup>1</sup>
2. Despite the fact that the current audit system is seriously flawed – as has been discussed often, at length and on multiple Meta sites – it is, nonetheless, a **vital** part of the review system. The potential damage caused by bad ("robo") reviewers far outweighs the "slings and arrows" suffered by good reviewers (such as yourself) from an occasional bad audit.
3. Whenever a reviewer encounters such an audit, they should – as you have done here – raise the issue on the particular site's Meta. That way, moderators and other community members can take actions (like voting, editing or closing/reopening) on the post that will prevent it from being selected for future audits.

So, what can be done about this issue? This has also been discussed *ad nauseam* on Meta sites. I don't want to speak for the moderator team, but one suggestion (with at least *some* support from the mods) has been to have them (or even staff) manually select posts to be used as Review Audits. This *may* work for the smaller sites but, on Stack Overflow, the sheer scale of the review system (many thousands of reviews each day) would likely make this task far too much of a burden. (I don't know how many posts are in the audit pool at any given time, nor how often that pool is refreshed; however, even as it is, I have been presented with the same audit multiple times on numerous occasions.)

Another point worth noting is that nothing was done to address or improve the audit-selection process in the 'recent' round of changes/improvements to the review queue system. This is notable in that it sends (to me, at least) a strong signal that SO Staff aren't especially concerned about the issue.

And, to end with a suggestion: Maybe keep the automatic selection process as it is, but add a step that requires a moderator to manually assess each selected post and approve its use, before it becomes active. That *may* be a workable compromise between the current "score-based" system (which will *always* be prone to errors such as the selection of the post you raised here) and a fully manual process that would simply add too much work to the (already overloaded) moderator team.

---

<sup>1</sup> There was a short period when a bug in the *processing* of audits in First Questions and First Answers caused multiple failures and, consequently, some otherwise good reviewers to be suspended. But that has now been fixed and, as far as I can remember, moderators were able to lift any suspensions that happened because of that bug.

Comment: Just an observation: Are you aware that you used (Parentheses) a Lot, capital L? It doesn't exactly make for easy reading.