# What should I do about ChatGPT content in questions (not answers)?

Tags: discussion, questions, chatgpt

I came across [a question today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74722287) that pasted a ChatGPT answer into the question. How can I handle such a case?

Comment: If the content isn't helpful to the post, and it's noise, edit it out. The user in question, however, is misusing the code fence/block markdown; answers from ChatGPT isn't code and shouldn't be identified as code. Text from ChatGPT should be in a quoteblock.

Comment: @Larnu revised the question to make it more general. In this case it was noise, how about if the ChatGPT answer does add some relevant info?

Comment: *"how about if the ChatGPT answer does add some relevant info?"* If it's not properly attributed then, at the bare minimum, it's not following the referencing guidelines and at worst it's malicious plagiarism. Though [ChatGPT answers are currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1), so if you see a ChatGPT answer at the moment, then you should probably be flagging it as such.

Comment: @Larnu it seems all ChatGPT content is banned, whether it's in questions or answers.

Comment: You were asking about answers in your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421960/what-to-do-about-chatgpt-content-in-questions-not-answers?noredirect=1#comment937975_421960), @bad_coder , hence why I mentioned answers.

Comment: @Larnu yes, I said the user posted an answer in the question - I'm unaware of ChatGPT also generating questions :P

Comment: An example of ChatGPT-generated code in [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76521808/warning-maximum-update-depth-exceeded-useeffect-problem/76522091#comment134975665_76522091): *"I've done prompt engineering to compose this code"*

Answer (score 11):

We do not need to go to every existing rule and every existing answer and inject "ChatGPT" into it. The only thing that is special about it is that it is being abused on a large scale because it is easy to do so.

The answer to this question is exactly the same as the answer to the question "I came across a question today that pasted an answer into the question. How to handle such a case?". Well:

[What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que)

I'm sure there are numerous meta posts which answer permutations of it, like "... and the answer is bad".

Comment: The answer to this question isn't the same as in the other cases, I just looked carefully at the ChatGPT announcement and the last paragraph states all ChatGPT content is banned whether it's in answers or questions. So this raises the issue of whether editing out the content is enough or the question should be closed/deleted due to the specific ban - a matter of policy that hasn't been addressed yet.

Comment: Also, quoting the announcement: *"If a user is believed to have used ChatGPT after this temporary policy is posted, sanctions will be imposed to prevent users from continuing to post such content"* I'm unsure if it's moderator flag worthy.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR:

- Edit out the answer from the question.
- Flag the question for moderator attention with an explanation along the lines of: *"This question had an AI generated answer inside it. I edited it out but according to policy flagging as this is banned"*.
- Leave a comment on the question explaining that answers don't go in the question and that content from CGPT is strictly not allowed.

---

The way I see it, there are three aspects to address here.

First of all, to remove the specific-case issue: in the example you gave, the use of CGPT is purely noise and shouldn't even warrant a special treatment, IMO. It is semantically the same as if it had something like: *"Even Wikipedia couldn't help me: <quote from Wikipedia>"*. That's just noise and could (should) be edited out.

Now in case you meant this as a more general question, we have two aspects:

1. Answers shouldn't be posted in questions. This is a Q&A site and posts should stick to the format. Follow the same guideline as [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) (*caveat coming up)
2. [Content produced by CGPT is currently banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). While a bit hidden away in all the commotion, the guideline seems to be to [flag for moderator attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned#comment937179_421867).

(*promised caveat:) Combining (2) with (1) it's probably best not to actually post the answer as a CW (or any other form), and modify the comment you would leave with the guideline about CGPT.