# Are questions about ChatGPT code okay to ask?

Tags: discussion, rules, chatgpt

If I want to verify if a script or code ChatGPT wrote would actually work and do as I want, can I ask a question about it or is it not allowed?

Comment: There is already precedent. What is the meta question (the corresponding question on Stack Overflow is deleted now)? Or meta answer?

Comment: According to the [last paragraph of this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421880/how-can-we-determine-whether-an-answer-used-chatgpt) the ban applies to all posts, so I'd advise against. Just assume it's well written garbage and you probably won't be too wrong.

Comment: Or maybe it was *[What should I do about ChatGPT content in questions (not answers)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421960/what-should-i-do-about-chatgpt-content-in-questions-not-answers)*

Comment: What would be your *specific* question about the ChatGPT code? When the answer to "does it work" is "no", will you fetch new code from ChatGPT and ask again? Instead of asking "Does this ChatGPT code do what I want?", why not directly "How to do what I want?"?

Comment: If only there was some way to just run code to see if it works or not.  Oh well.  Or even if there was some kind of future utopia where you could run other code that tests if your code works or not.  I guess we'll never see such advances in our lifetime.

Comment: Wasn't there a meta post with an example of where the question on Stack Overflow was asking about the (wrong) code output from ChatGPT?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: No. I found the Stack Overflow question (now deleted): *[How to minimize this función \[sic\] in matlab \[sic\] using \[sic\] \[sic\] wolf algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74725785/how-to-minimize-this-funci%c3%b3n-in-matlab-using-wolf-algorithm)* - *"I tried the ChatGPT but the output doesn't work or I am doing something wrong."*. There isn't a link back to meta in it. There must have been a reference to the Stack Overflow question on meta. (It may or may not be the [Wolff algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolff_algorithm) that is referred to.)

Comment: "Does this code work" is a strange question. If you want to verify that code works, test it. "How do I test this code" can be a good question, but only if there's something making that task nontrivial.

Comment: OK, I found it. The reference was in [a ***comment***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned#comment938005_421831).

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate of a newer question because the newer question specifically asks for a site policy (e.g., from a moderator), rather than inviting a general discussion. The discussion had the chance to happen here, but... didn't really.

Comment: OK, the comment is gone. Note to self: Quote comments in the future

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and say: No, this is not okay.

So let's say you ask ChatGPT "How do I do this?", and it gives you code. Then you ask Stack Overflow "Does this code do this?" – and let's assume the answer is no.
Now what?

You ask ChatGPT *again* "How do I do this?", and it gives you code. Then you ask Stack Overflow "Does this code do this?" – and let's assume the answer is no.
Now what?

…

You ask ChatGPT *again* "How do I do this?", and it gives you code. Then you ask Stack Overflow "Does this code do this?" – and let's assume the answer is yes.
What a waste of everyone's time.

If you want to know "How do I do this?" and consider Stack Overflow for Q&A, ask us directly "How do I do this?".

Comment: ... But you may still ask 'ChatGPT' to proofread the Title for your Question to make sense grammatically before posting it... :wink:

Comment: If someone says "I'm trying to do task T, so I wrote code C, which uses the A algorithm, but when I run it on data D it gives output Z instead of X. How come?", then that's on-topic. We can write answers that correct their misunderstanding and fix their code. But if someone posts some random code that they didn't write and they don't understand, and they don't explain which bits they do and don't understand, then that's off-topic, IMHO, no matter where the random code came from. The only way to help people like that is to stop them from cargo-cult coding.

Comment: Your scenario is **not why ChatGPT is a problem**, and there are plenty of ways to get to your scenario without ChatGPT already (plenty of terrible tutorials and blog posts on the internet, and people without the motivation to figure stuff out for themselves). If a question is on topic otherwise and attributes the code, then that is fine. You can't generate such questions at a rate of 30 posts/hour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree that getting code from ChatGPT is equivalent to getting it from tutorials or blogs because ChatGPT can generate a practically endless stream of different variants. One very much **can** generate "does this <ChatGPT code> work as desired?" questions at an enormous rate.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: and all those would be off-topic. Most of all, **this isn't what is happening**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is what this meta question is asking about. That the new meta question is about a related but different situation doesn’t change this one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: the issue here is that *whatever the source of the code* such questions would be off-topic. "Does this piece of code I found in the alley behind the walmart work?" is just as much too broad. My point is that this isn't a problem unique to ChatGPT.