# Asking about ChatGPT without using content generated by it

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

[Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/1595451) prohibits the use of content generated by ChatGPT, this means besides using ChatGPT content to answer questions the following is banned too:

- <s>Asking help to fix code generated by ChatGPT</s> <sup>see [Should we flag human-written questions that use code generated by ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422439/1595451)</sup>
- Asking help to elucidate what is correct between two or more ChatGPT responses to the same question
- ...

Since ChatGPT hasn't an API, I'm wondering it there is anything that might be OK to ask on Stack Overflow strictly about ChatGPT.

---

Some numbers from GitHub

- https://github.com/search?q=chatgpt returns 1,560 repository results.
- https://github.com/topics/awesome?q=chatgpt returns 5 repository results.

---

Related

- [Are questions about ChatGPT code okay to ask?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422064/1595451)
- [Where to ask / migrate questions about ChatGPT](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384797/289691)

Comment: It doesn't seem reasonable for us to come up with an a priori list of "you can ask this question". The general case seems to be adequately handled by the [on-topic page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which seems more than adequate with respect to limiting questions about this particular subject. What circumstance makes having an additional special rule desirable beyond the ones we already have (i.e. the ban on ChatGPT generated content)?

Comment: I don't think that we need a special rule, I just trying to clarify my understanding about what ChatGPT is and what could be done with it by programmers that might be on-topic here. Recently there was [a question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38268/42632) originally posted on AI about ChatGPT "bug" that had a lot of views (> 20k). Using Chrome Developer Tools the OP found that a network error have occurred.

Comment: If we sum up the views of the copies on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74780137/1595451) and [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168202/88163) resulting of migrations that later were rejected, the views  are > 50k.

Comment: Another circumstance is that ChatGPT availability is limited. Few moments ago it showed "We're experiencing exceptionally high demand. Please hang tight as we work on scaling our systems."

Comment: I don't see how any of that affects what's on-topic or off-topic here, or sets up a special circumstance for ChatGPT compared to anything else.

Comment: I make a prediction: questions about the ChatGPT API are going to be answered by ChatGPT itself. People are going to think they're *so* funny and clever when they do. So in the end this question is going to be interesting trivia rather than useful :) It is only when ChatGPT is going to be a paid service that questions about it are going to become useful.

Answer (score 17):

Ugh.  Yes, this is a different circumstance than just copying and pasting the content from the bot itself.  But there's not really a lot of source code or even an official API to go off of.

What kind of question *could* we answer about this thing that isn't limited to some generic answer about chatbots, natural language processing and machine learning??

***Ugh***.

Answer (score 0):

On January 9 there was 20 questions tagged [chatgpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chatgpt). This tag hasn't a tag wiki.

Most of the questions that are open look to be about the Open AI API. Those that are specifically about https://chat.openai.com/chat are closed as off-topic, below there are some examples:

- [Which is larger? Comparison of ranges between ChatGPT vs. Google search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74976690/1595451)
- [Can I fine tune ChatGPT on a Text Corpus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75018693/1595451)
- [How to stop ChatGPT from running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75037578/1595451)
- [Chatgpt says O(2^n) is less performant than O (n2^n) is this true?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75040954/1595451)
- [How can I bypass chatGPT limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75048188/1595451)

Related

- [Disambiguation [chatgpt] and [openai]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422589/1595451)