# Should an initial solution to a problem be posted as an answer, instead of including it in the question and asking for other solutions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There is a question which can be summarized as:

> How can I do X?
>
> I tried Y but it failed.
>
> I found solution Z, are there other solutions?

Solution Z was edited into the question by the asker (A) shortly after it was posted, and approximately at the same time (within one minute, technically the edit came first) another user (B) posted that same solution as an answer.

Then, user C edited the question to remove the "I found solution Z" part, claiming it belongs in an answer. Then user D reverted that edit, claiming that solution Z was part of the question. A discussion ensued in the comments about which of the edits was correct.

The question did not ask about any specifics of solution Z, other than answers were not expected to repeat it.

When posting or editing questions, where is the appropriate place for working solutions that have already been found, but other solutions are sought?

---

<sub>I'm not inclined to link to the specific question myself, in order to not draw too much attention to it, since as you may have guessed I'm one of users B/C/D and have posted an answer to the question. It should not be difficult to find it.</sub>

Comment: Since the asker accepted an answer giving the same solution, the inclusion of that solution in the question makes no sense. If they were only seeking alternative approaches, they wouldn't have accepted the same answer.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que

Comment: "are there other solutions?" vibe would make question off-topic as unclear/too broad/looking for discussion... OP either still have a problem with an approach (and exact criteria for "other" need to be included) or doesn't - than there is no question in the question.

Comment: Does the existence of Z actually refine the question? That is: are non-Z solutions characterized in some interesting way that doesn't boil down to "not being Z"?

Comment: This is too abstract. According to your title, it is an "initial solution". What is that? Is it something they can continue with? Does it answer their question? According to your made-up question body it does not, because they're asking for alternatives to the solution they found. Therefore it is not an answer to their question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Z is a working solution which the asker discovered on their own shortly after posting the question, and they could have continued with that, but they were interested in alternatives (for reasons not stated in the question).

Comment: Then you post a comment asking for clarification, you don't roll back an edit adding context and then post an answer.

Comment: @mkrieger1 what I was trying to get at is better explained by anatolyg's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the question explains why solution Z is bad/unacceptable (e.g. it requires some recent version of a compiler, while OP is stuck with an old version), then the solution belongs with the question. The question is then "how can I do X without Z?", which is a perfectly good question.

If the solution is an acceptable answer, it belongs in the answer box. If the solution is somehow unacceptable for OP, but it's not clear why, it also should be an answer. In this case, including Z in the question is unnecessary; it will make the question less clear and reduce visibility of solution Z.

Answer (score 5):

Valid arguments can be made for either case:

**Initial solution as an answer**: If a future user searches for problem X and finds this question, they should be able to find all existing solutions in answers. If Z is also contained in the question, it is more difficult to discern whether it is actually a solution, or only a demonstration of the problem.

**Initial solution as part of the question**: Sometimes, questions can be better understood by demonstrating both working and non-working attempts to solve a problem. If a future user has a similar problem and finds this question, they may more easily identify whether their problem is identical to X by seeing solution Z as compared to Y.

Answer (score 5):

An initial solution is still an answer. There is already [community consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) that answers should not be edited into the question and should be posted separately as an answer.

If the main concern is that:

> but other solutions are sought?

It is still the best to have the initial solution in an answer since having an answer does not mean that new / other answers to the same questions aren't welcome.

In my opinion many of the cases where the OP might edit the answer into the question and ask for other solutions are simply because the OP isn't aware that [self-answers are encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Rather than leaving the answer in the question it is appropriate to roll it back and encourage them to post an answer.

Comment: They're looking for alternatives to the solution they found, so that can not be an answer to their question.

Comment: @CodeCaster no, they added that solution into the question later, after they had posted the question for about 8 minutes. Given in this case their question was simple it is possible to find a solution in 8 minutes. I believe they didn't post it as an answer because they might not be sure if there is something better or if their solution has some problems.

Comment: If they didn't want to use their solution they should have explained why as described in [anatolyg's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424562/should-an-initial-solution-to-a-problem-be-posted-as-an-answer-instead-of-inclu/424608#424608)

Comment: The problem here is that "initial solution" is a vague term, and that the question here is about the generic case, not the specific one that can be easily found through OP's profile. You are stating a rule that questions cannot contain any solution, which is incorrect. A solution that is not satisfactory for whatever reason must still be within the question, not be posted as an answer, because it is part of the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster "_A solution that is not satisfactory for whatever reason must still be within the question_" OP never said that the solution was not satisfactory (in the actual as well as the described scenario here), that was just assumed. I agree that if the OP explains why that solution is unsatisfactory it should stay in the question.

Comment: _"I found solution Z, are there other solutions?"_ - that is asking for alternatives, therefore there must be some reason that Z is not satisfactory.

Comment: @CodeCaster and again that was edited in after the actual question was posted. OP might as well have posted an answer, the existence of that answer (in an ideal case) shouldn't stop other users from answering and (again ideally) should stop people from posting the same answer.

Comment: No, it was not. The edit came before the answer. The answer is low-hanging fruit to a duplicate question anyway. If we're so interested in curating, then that was the route that should have been taken: leave the edit, find a duplicate. We don't roll back an edit to a trivial question because a trivial answer was given one minute after the edit by a 70K rep user who should've known better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253553/discussion-between-abdul-aziz-barkat-and-codecaster).

Answer (score 2):

The initial solution is part of the question in fact so ideally it should be part of the question as posted on Stack Overflow. If it were posted as an answer it can be voted on, flagged, or even deleted, actions which make no sense given that the "answer" is not really an attempt to answer the question.

As to the specific example, there's no great resolution. People should not post incomplete questions and then gradually edit in the details.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the framing of this question (what is an "initial solution", precisely?) nor the discussion that stems from the narrowness thereof.

Solutions that are not intended to be solutions, so which are not satisfactory for reasons known or unknown to us, **belong in the question**. It is part of "what have you tried?", namely "I found this code but it's not what I'm looking for".

The (trivial) answer was posted after the edit. The answerer, a 70K rep user, should know the game. It would appear that the solution the asker found, equal to the answer that was posted around the same time, did not fulfill their requirements. The answerer should have taken their loss, removed the answer, ask for clarification in comments.